# Can We show the string value as a measure on mondrian olap

Tags: olap, pentaho, mondrian

I want to show the string value as one of the measure value. When a fact table has a integer value and string value respectively and also has some foreign table's keys. Then I could show the integer value as a measure value, but I couldn't show the string value as a measure. Because [Measure element](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/xml_schema.php#Measure) in schema of cube (written in XML) doesn't allow that a measure value doesn't have 'aggregator'(It specify the aggregate function of measure values). Of course I understood that we can't aggregate some string values. But I want to show the string value of the latest level in hierarchy.

I read following article. [A figure](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/display_props.png) (around middle of this page) shows a cube that contains string value as a measure value. But this is an example of Property value of Dimension table, so this string value isn't contain in fact table. I want to show the string value that contains in fact table.

[A Simple Date Dimension for Mondrian Cubes](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/07/a-simple-date-dimension-for-mondrian-cubes/)

Anyone have some idea that can be shown the string value as a measure value? Or I have to edit Mondrian's source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem and solved it by setting the `aggregator` attribute in the measure tag to `max`.
e.g.

```
\<Measure name="Comment" datatype="String" column="comment" caption="Comment" aggregator="max"/\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need to be a measure?

If no aggregation would naturally be applied to it and you just want the string value, it is a dimension, not a measure.  Trying to force it to be a measure is not the best approach.

I think the figure you reference is just showing a drillthrough, and that the only *actual* 
measure is Turnover.  The report layout is slightly misleading in terms of dimensions and measures.

You can just use the fact table again in the schema as a dimension table if for some reason you don't want to split this out into a separate physical table.

Sounds like the string may be high cardinality to the integer, possibly 1:1.  Depending upon the size of your cube, this might or might not be a performance challenge.  But don't try to make it a measure.

Good luck!